# Write a recursive function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, recursive-query

```
ORDER_ID                                TRANSACT_TIME
AAA                                     24-JUL-17 04.05.54.491000000 PM
AAA                                     24-JUL-17 04.05.54.496000000 PM
AAA                                     24-JUL-17 04.05.54.504000000 PM
BBB                                     24-JUL-17 04.05.54.491000000 PM
BBB                                     24-JUL-17 04.05.54.497000000 PM
BBB                                     24-JUL-17 04.05.54.505000000 PM
...                                     ...
```

This data (Order ID and Transaction_Time) is being published to the table every hour or so.

I am trying to create a function (or sql query) in Oracle SQL to ensure that every subsequent transaction time is greater than or equal to the previous entry.

Basically the second entry in AAA cannot have an older transaction time than the first entry in AAA and so on.

I would like some guidance on how I can go about writing this function. One idea I found is to write a recursive function, I tried something like this but I'm not entirely sure what is going on:

```
        Note: PREV_TRANS_TIME is an alias I generated to grab the transaction 
    time of the previous transaction (meaning for first entry PREV_TRANS_TIME = null)

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TransactTimeChecker(PREV_TRANS_TIME) RETURN STRING AS
        BEGIN
            IF prev_trans_time > transact_time THEN
                        RETURN (I'm not sure what to write 
                               here but I need to fix the entries so the order is adjusted)
            ELSIF prev_trans_time <= transact_time THEN
                        RETURN (we are good, no problem)
            ELSE
                        --Do nothing
            END IF;
        END;
```

Comment: You use words like "subsequent", "previous", "second", "first" when you refer to rows with the same `order_id`. That implies they are ordered somehow. Unlike what you see on paper or on screen, rows in a database are **not ordered**. You need an explicit ordering criterion before you can speak of "subsequent" and the like. The obvious ordering would be by `transact_time` but apparently in your problem that is not the case, since you must check that transaction times are, in fact, in the right order. What **other** ordering is there, to determine "first", "second" etc.? You didn't mention any.

Comment: perhaps a check constraint on the table might be the best solution for this requirement.  Have you looked at them (e.g. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php).

Comment: I agree with @Mathguy . This seems like an architectural problem. What generates `order_id, transact_time`? Presumably something outside of the database. Why does `order by transact_time` not guarantee the correct ordering?

Comment: @mathguy I am using order id as my order criteria. Once my entries are ordered based on order ID, I know what my previous and next orders are.

Comment: @SuhailPrasathong - That, again, doesn't make any sense. Just take the first three rows and ignore the other three. How does ORDER_ID **order** those rows? How does it tell you, of the three rows, which is first, which is second and which is third? (It can't, because all three rows have the same ORDER_ID - you can't distinguish them from each other based on ORDER_ID alone.) I understand you GROUP (partition) by ORDER_ID, but you don't **order** by it.

Comment: @mathguy, you're right. My apologies. I populated version ID's for each field and that's what I am ordering these by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need recursion.  I'm assuming prev_trans_time is the last used order time.  You want to wait until you get a new time to create the next transaction.  Your function can iterate until the system time goes up.

```
declare
    transact_time date := sysdate; 
begin
    while (prev_trans_time > transact_time) loop
        transact_time := sysdate;
    end loop;
    return transact_time;
end;
```

Comment: If you want the transact time to be unique because it's part of the key, you'd be better off using an identity or sequence number as the key and keeping the actual transaction time.

Comment: This suggestion, if implemented, may lead to big headaches, and depending on application it may be borderline illegal. The transaction time is the transaction time, not some other time calculated who-knows-in-what-manner. Imagine I may pay a big fine unless I pay my bill by 12 midnight on April 30, but your application says I didn't - it shows transaction time three minutes later. Who will pay my fine, and why?